# Unlock src folder in react deploy github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my react website to Github pages, and I've followed all instructions in [this](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages) tutorial. The deployment is done well, and the web is already up, but I got a problem here, the `src` folder seems locked here, and I want to make it accessible for anyone who wants to look at it

[image]

is there any way to "unlock" this `src` folder in my react project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a remnant of a submodule which is no longer configured. The output of [`git ls-files --stage`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt---stage) shows the mode of the `src` entry as *`160000`* which refers to a submodule:

```sh
[...]
160000 df78a5d08d49f10082d4d5c402bbb1dcf714c20f 0   src
100644 19762936f6c1b0e5274fdebc6ed78fe4b37038e6 0   tailwind.config.js
100644 25ed6eee8f2435e1ae8eeee447d0b33d73c72f41 0   yarn.lock
```

Since there is no `.gitmodules` anymore, you can remove the entry if no longer needed:

```
git rm --cached src
git commit -m "Remove src submodule"
```

Comment: I've removed the ```--cached src``` but the src folder in my Github is still locked, is there any other way to open it?